# How to extract day, month, and year from date returned by QML Calender?

Tags: date, qml, qt5, qtquick2

The `Calendar` [`clicked`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-calendar.html#clicked-signal) signal returns a date as follows:

```
2015-11-13T00:00:00
```

However, I would like to have a date formatted like this:

```
Fri Nov 13 2015
```

This is what I tried:

```
onSelectedDateChanged: 
{
     calender.visible = false;
     selectedDate = selectedDate.toLocaleTimeString(Qt.LocalDate, Locale.ShortFormat);
     textOfSelectedDate.text = Date.fromLocaleTimeString(Qt.LocalDate, selectedDate, Locale.ShortFormat)}
}
```

`textOfSelectedDate` is the `id` of the text box where this date will be displayed.

How can I extract day, month, and year in a desired format from `Date` returned by `Calender`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

QML's [date](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-date.html) type extends Javascript's [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp). Thus you can do:

```
onSelectedDateChanged: {
    const day = selectedDate.getDate();
    const month = selectedDate.getMonth() + 1; //assuming you want 1..12, getMonth()'s return value is zero-based!
    const year = selectedDate.getFullYear();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, `date` is similar to JS date type. So you can use all its functions, like `getDate()` etc. See it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Also, you can use [`Qt.formatDate()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#formatDate-method) object to format the result. In your case it can be as follows:

```
onClicked: {
    console.log(Qt.formatDate(date,"ddd MMM d yyyy")) 
}
```